# Block view contextual filters

Tags: views, 8

**What I want to achieve**

I need to create a single view to display latest content of each content type. And I have content type: Article, Basic page.

**What I do**

I have create a View with a display Block called *Latest content by Bundle*. In this view, I add Contextual filters Content: *Content type*. I set *When the filter value is not avaiable* to *Provide default value: Content ID from URL*.

I try the view preview, type the value `article` and it display the articles content. I then go to Block layout, place the block view that I created to a region.

**My problem**

When I configure the Block view, there are option to select content type, but the dropdown item is empty.

[image]

I'm expecting list of content type displayed. Is this correct? Or there are something that I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can pass an argument into a block like that.

However, you can do it with page manager.

- Make sure AJAX is enabled in your view
- Install & enable page manager https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager
- You may need to [apply this patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager/issues/2799885) with composer for the following steps to work
- Go to `structure > pages`
- Add a new page manager page like this

[image]

- Skip the next screen (click next)
- Set up a context like this

[image]
[image]

- Skip the next two screens (click next)
- Add your view block like this

[image]

- Now go to `<your_url>/latest/article` and the page should list your articles
- You can add other pages/contexts for other content types

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed answers. Gonna give it a try. But waht if it is a Block? because block doesn't have path.

Comment: In this example you use page manager to create a page with a path, and then you place that block in the page. See the first screenshot `/latest/{bundle_type}`

Comment: Yep, it is working like you explain. Thank you. I also need to install module _Panels_. So I can select Variant type Panels.